# sed text replacement with file seperator

Tags: linux, sed

**My file** has multiple columns like this

```
A   B   C (jan)   D   E   F (feb)   G (mar)   H
```

(i.e. there are tabs between A and B, B and C,(jan) and D but there is a space between C and (jan). And I want to replace only those spaces with underscores.

So, the output will be like

```
A   B   C_(jan)   D   E   F_(feb)   G_(mar)   H
```

any comment?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just removing the parenthesis (replace with spaces to keep positions intact)

```
$ sed 's/[()]/ /g' file
A       B       C  jan  D       E       F  feb  G  mar  H
```

removing the contents as well

```
$ sed -E 's/\([^)]+\)//g' file
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H
```

not clear what you asked.

still not clear what you want, you say you want to remove parenthesis, but the example shows them.

Here are two more variations

```
$ sed -E 's/ (\([^)]+\))/_\1/g' file
A       B       C_(jan) D       E       F_(feb) G_(mar) H

$ sed -E 's/ \(([^)]+)\)/_\1/g' file
A       B       C_jan   D       E       F_feb   G_mar   H
```

Comment: I want to keep words between parenthesis but without spaces between those words and the previous columns. So, now the file is like column_1\tcolumn_2\tcolumn3 (info)\t -- but what I want is like column_1\tcolumn_2\tcolumn3_(info)\t -- only will replace spaces between parentheses and the previous column id with underscores. I tried what you suggested but it only removes one parenthesis like column_1\tcolumn_2\tcolumn3_(info\t

Comment: Thanks, the last you suggested gave the output that I want!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it this regex: `sed -E 's/ (\(.+\))/_\1/g' file` doesn't produce the same result as this one: `sed -E 's/ (\([^)]+\))/_\1/g' file` ? In other words, the "any character" `.` versus the negation of no character `[^]`

Comment: Greedy match. It will match everything until the last closing parenthesis.